# jpa update/delete queries doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

service class

```
@Service
public class UpdateService {
 @Autowired
 private ArBuildingRepository arBuildingRepository;

 public void updateArBuilding(boolean newNode, String rca){
     arBuildingRepository.updateByRca(newNode, rca);
 }

}
```

custom query in repo interface

```
public interface ArBuildingRepository extends JpaRepository<ArBuilding, Long> {
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE ArBuilding ar SET ar.newNode = ?1 where ar.rca = ?2")
void updateByRca(boolean newNode, String rca);
}
```

error:

```
2017-04-17 19:16:13.152 ERROR 12212 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep : Encountered an error executing step     step6 in job importUserJob

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.updateByRca(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.post.code.normalizer.service.UpdateService.updateArBuilding(UpdateService.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
at com.post.code.normalizer.batch.BuildingProcessor.process(BuildingProcessor.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
at com.post.code.normalizer.batch.BuildingProcessor.process(BuildingProcessor.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at com.post.code.normalizer.batch.BatchConfiguration.perform(BatchConfiguration.java:394) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_101]...
```

im using spring-batch, and When the ItemReader transfers data to the processor, before finishing the data processing in the processor, it must update the data in the old table with my custom update query.

Comment: How does your spring configuration look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the exception you have no transaction running.

You need to set up a transaction manager and use @EnableTransactionManagement in the configuration. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html